# What is 'de' doing in this sentence?

Tags: de

I am looking at a sentence in a novel from 1968. It reads 'C'était ce qu'on pouvait faire de plus miséricordieux'. In English this reads, 'It was the most merciful thing'. I am wondering why the phrase is 'de plus miséricordieux' rather than 'le plus miséricordieux'?

Answer (score 3):

*Le plus miséricordieux* would be non grammatical.

After a indefinite pronoun or expression, we use the preposition ***de*** to introduce an adjective:

Something different → *Quelque chose **de** différent*

Comment: Indeed, compare *la chose la plus miséricordieuse*

Comment: Bien sûr, c'est ça.

Answer (score 1):

A point to understand as a preliminary is the difference between  what is called (in French) "*le comparatif*" and what is called "*le superlatif relatif*".  The adverb "*plus*" (superiority) or "*moins*" (inferiority)  is used for both of them ; the mark of the latter is the addition of the article "le".

**superlatif relatif** (LBU, 14ème édition, § 987) (caractères gras de user LPH)

> Formes du superlatif relatif.
> **a)** Le superlatif relatif a la même forme que le comparatif de supériorité ou d'infériorité. Il s'en distingue seulement par la présence de l'article défini.
> ♦ Il est PLUS aimable. →  Il est **LE** PLUS aimable.
> ♦ Il travaille PLUS (ou MOINS ou MIEUX) à la maison qu'au bureau → Il travaille **LE** PLUS (ou **LE** MOINS ou **LE** MIEUX) à la maison.
> **b)**  Cependant, dans deux cas, le superlatif n'a pas de marque le distinguant du comparatif.
> 1 °
> Quand l'adjectif au superlatif relatif précède le nom
> ♦ C'est le PLUS beau film que j'aie vu (l'article est celui qui détermine le nom). [cf. C'est **le** film **le** plus beau que j'aie jamais vu.]
> ♦  Mon PLUS grand souhait est de vous épouser.
> 2° Quand l'adjectif au superlatif accompagne *ce* pronom relatif.
> ♦ Voilà ce que j'ai trouvé de MOINS cher.
> ♦ Ce qu'il y a de PLUS beau n'est pas visible.
> ♦ Ce qu'il a vu de PLUS étrange, il n'ose pas le raconter.
> ♦ Tout ce que l'Idylle a de PLUS enfantin (BAUDEL., Fl. du m., Paysage).

"b) 2°" gives the rule explaining this apparent anomaly, and the corresponding translation into English is therefore correct.

<sub>Note: I suppose that there'll be no problem reading the French of the reference and so I do not bother to add a translation. If something remained unclear, do not hesitate to ask for explanations.</sub>